# how to prevent scaling of text and border while scaling path

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

hi I am trying to scale svg shape path by

```
svgcanvas.attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")");
```

but it scales all elements added on the svgcanvas(text and border)

I need text and border are same as like previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [group elements](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js) by putting only the elements which you want to transform into a `<g>` element, then putting your desired transformation in the `transform` attribute of the `<g>` element.

Comment: but I am using single svg element for the path and others

Comment: If I am doing with different elements for svg than it is not posible to transform path related text on its position.